# combine magento storeviews

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a Magento webshop where I have two storeviews for two languages, currencies and countries. The problem I'm facing right now is that one of these countries is multi-lingual and I would therefore like to offer both languages already present in my two storeviews to the country in question.

The simple solution would be to just create a third storeview and have a language switch between those two views for that country.  But since all the language already exists in the existing two views I'm a bit confused on how to best use whats already in place.

If it wasn't for currency and shipping differences between the two countries I could easily just reuse the first storeview for the second country, but I'd need to combine the language from the first view with the currency and shipping options from the second into a third storeview.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this without manually keeping two sets of the same language for all my texts?

Comment: I think the better way was to create stores for the countries and store views for the languages. I don't know how to do this now, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you would use Stores (Store Groups) for different countries. But have in mind that the base currency scope is Website (means your customers can't do payment transactions with different currencies than the one set for the Website). If you are ok with that, then your solution would be:

```
"Each Country" -> "Store"
"Each language in that country" -> "Store View"
```

It doesn't matter if you have multiple store views that would have the same language set, Magento only takes one translated text (under app/locale). So you wouldn't end up with any duplicated text.

Comment: There's no configuration at the store group level.

Comment: @benmarks: not sure if I follow? What configuration are we talking about?

Comment: You mentioned setting store groups for countries, but you can't set any configuration at that level. It would be at website or store.

Comment: Okey, I think I understand what you mean and was able to find more information on the Magento website too. Thanks.